# MySQL Query help and outputting to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Below is an attached image of what I have so far.  1 = a feature and 2 = a benefit.

What I need to do is match the feature with the benefit.  The first #1 goes with the first #2

[image]

What I have so far is:

```
<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT FB_TEXT FROM `FB_DATA` WHERE `FB_MODELID` = "'.$sku_modelid.'" AND FB_TYPEID IN (1,2)')) { 

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['FB_TEXT']."</td></tr>";
    }

}
?>
```

Now this shows all results.  What needs to happen is this:

```
<tr>
   <td>Feature</td>
   <td>Benefit</td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I could make that happen?

Comment: How do you know which is the first one?

Comment: You know I am really not sure.. I just did a search for that model ID and that's what came up, and it matches up perfectly.

Comment: You need an order id, and check the first aswer below.

Comment: Drew, you're not showing us all the columns of the table, are you? Is my understanding correct that there's another column named `FB_MODELID` by which the feature and benefit are identified to be linked together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way the ensure this will happen correctly. Instead, you should link the 2 together, using a separate table and using indexes and unique identifiers for it.

If the Feature and benefit are always used together, you could also add another column to it.

This would make a table having 4 columns:

1. ID (unique)
2. Feature
3. Benefit
4. Text

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the others are on about, but if you know that when `FB_TYPEID` is `1` it is considered a feature and when `FB_TYPEID` is `2`, it is considered a benefit, then ordering is easy.

Use this query:

```
SELECT
    `FB_TYPEID`,
    `FB_TEXT`
FROM
    `FB_DATA`
WHERE
    `FB_MODELID` = theModelIdYouAreLookingFor AND
    `FB_TYPEID` IN (1,2)
ORDER BY
    CASE `FB_TYPEID`
        WHEN 1 THEN 0
        WHEN 2 THEN 1
        # switch this to:
        # WHEN 2 THEN 0
        # WHEN 1 THEN 1
        # if you want benefit to show first
    END
```

Make sure you protect yourself against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The way you query with `mysqli` now, is vulnerable to SQL injection (presuming `$sku_modelid` was not sanitized before). You should really be using prepared statements with bound parameters. Something like:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT
        `FB_TYPEID`,
        `FB_TEXT`
    FROM
        `FB_DATA`
    WHERE
        `FB_MODELID` = ? AND
        `FB_TYPEID` IN (1,2)
    ORDER BY
        CASE `FB_TYPEID`
            WHEN 1 THEN 0
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
        END
';
if( $statement = $mysqli->prepare( $sql ) )
{
    // bind $sku_modelid to the first (and only) questionmark (placeholder) as an integer
     $statement->bind_param( 'i', $sku_modelid );

     // execute the prepared statement
     if( $statement->execute() )
     {
        // bind FB_TYPEID to $typeId and FB_TEXT to $text
         $statement->bind_result( $typeId, $text );
         while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
        {
            // echo the table row
            if( $typeId == 1 ) echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $text . '</td>';
            if( $typeId == 2 ) echo '</tr>';
        }
     }
}
```

(Could be missing something here, as I never use the `mysqli` library. But I believe it should work.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.  I can't seem to get it working quite right.  It outputs <tr><td>Feature</td><tr><td>Feature</td><tr><td>Feature</td>   - and at one point it gives two tds.  Here is a preview http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/714/previewpe.jpg/

Comment: if only I could create an HTML table with <tr><td>feature</td><td>feature</td><td>feature</td></tr> <tr><td>benefit</td><td>beneft</td><td>benefit</td></tr>  then it would be soo much easier.

Comment: @Drew: O, wait, I see what the others were on about now. I thought there would only ever be one benefit and one feature per `FB_MODELID`. Silly me. In that case, they are right of course that you are not able to distinguish what feature should be paired with what benefit. I think you indeed need to rethink the database design.

Comment: Really?  There's nothing I can do?  The database has like 40,000 rows that a company sent us so we can't really edit it.  Hmm.

Comment: @Drew: isn't there any other data by which you are able to identify what feature should be paired with what benefit? If not, I think your should tell the company that sent it to you, and ask for a database that *does* provide this data.

Comment: @Drew: I think you should ask yourself or your manager/superior/client this: Do we need to match particular features with particular benefits in the table rows? If so, how do we distinguish the link between them, based on the data provided? If not (a random feature may be paired with a random benefit), then come back with a comment (or expand your question). I can't help you any further based on the data if they need to be linked though. It's a decision that needs to be internally decided upon first.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I understand that we need a better database design to accomplish what we want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very dangerous way to do this.

Technically, SQL doesn't have any concept of "Order".  Yes, in all actuality it orders things by the time you put them in there, but there **is no guarantee** that they will come out in that expected order.

You'd be best off creating two separate tables, one for "features" and one for "benefits.  Then join them with a foreign key.

```
SELECT * FROM features JOIN benefits ON features.link_id = benefits.link_id WHERE features.model_id = 1
```